# Moving between scenes crashes game with EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, exc-bad-access

First I would like to say that my game moves between scenes just fine (The first time). It starts with the menu scene that right now just has a button that says play game.

```
let play = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    play.frame = CGRect(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.4, width: 100, height: 100)
    play.setTitle("PLAY GAME", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    play.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    play.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    self.view?.addSubview(play)

func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    var gameScene = GameScene(size: self.frame.size)
    var transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
    gameScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

    let skView = view as SKView!
    skView.presentScene(gameScene, transition: transition)


    play.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

This button takes you to the other scene where you play the game. When you lose this function is called.

```
    func gameOver(){
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.title = "Game Over"
    alert.message = "Score: " + String(score)
    alert.addButtonWithTitle("Okay")
    alert.show()

    var gameStartScene = GameStartScene(size: self.frame.size)
    var transition = SKTransition.flipVerticalWithDuration(1.0)
    gameStartScene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill

    let skView = view as SKView!
    skView.presentScene(gameStartScene, transition: transition)

}
```

This take you back to the first sceen with the play button but when you press the "play game" button again for the second time the game crashes with the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Any ideas??

Comment: Like always after posting I figured it out...

I was declaring "play" globally like everyone knows you shouldn't....